# Extract the whole word from a textarea depending on where the caret is

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, caret

I have a html textarea and i need to extract the word from the text in it, depending on where the caret is.

So, if the caret is in a word, or just at the end of beginning (or end) of a word, i need to get that.

How can i do that? Im not looking for a library, just plain javascript.
Please help.

Comment: something like "foo^bar" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that will do the job. Basically, extract the caret position. Convert sentence to array. Loop array adding words lengths together, when length is greater than caret position you have found your word.

```
<html>
<script>


    function getCaret(node) {
      if (node.selectionStart) {
        return node.selectionStart;
      } else if (!document.selection) {
        return 0;
      }

      var c = "\001",
          sel = document.selection.createRange(),
          dul = sel.duplicate(),
          len = 0;

      dul.moveToElementText(node);
      sel.text = c;
      len = dul.text.indexOf(c);
      sel.moveStart('character',-1);
      sel.text = "";
      return len;
    }

    function getWord()
    {

        var el = document.getElementById('myText');
        var carret = getCaret(el);
        var words = el.value.split(' ');
        var x = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            debugger;
            x += words[i].length + 1;
            if(x > carret){ return words[i]; }
        }


    }

    function myWord()
    {
        var word = getWord();
        alert(word);
    }

</script>

<body>

    <button onclick="myWord();" >Get word</button>
    <textarea id="myText">This is a hallo world sentence</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing  var words = el.value.split(' ');  But it can be a new line (/n) or /r too

Comment: You can always do regex split. E.g. to split on word boundaries use: el.value.split(/\b/);   this will require a sight tweak to your algorithm though: x += words[i].length; (remove + 1;). The principal is there though. Dont forget to mark as answered.

Comment: because i needed to add that in my plugin. and that plugin is framework independent :P